# What happens to incoming server requests during garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm doing load testing with my Web service (let's just say I'm using Spring MVC with Tomcat). What I'm noticing is that my error rate (# of requests that return 200 status code/total # of requests) highly correlates with when GC happens. Therefore,

1. I wonder if all incoming requests get lost when GC happens because all other threads that are in motion got paused. True?
2. My second guess is that the reason GC happens is because I'm running out memory, which is why those requests return with a non-200 code.
3. What would be the best approach to address this problem?

Comment: 1. No. The socket stays open and data arriving is buffered. 2. Yes. 3. Get more memory or use less.

Comment: Per question 2, you should get a 408 back (timeout). The comment above should be marked as the answer. You could investigate which gc algorithm you are using and if it isn't one, move to a concurrent gc.